# Converting T(n) to Theta with floors

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science

```
public static int myfun2(int n) {
    int p, k, t;
    p=n;
    k=10;

    while(p>=1){
        k=k+p;
        for(t=n; t>=0; t=t-3){
            System.out.println(p + ", "+t);
            k++;

        }
        p=p/3;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Above is some code that I had to perform analysis on. I came up with the formula (⌊log3 (n)⌋+1)  ×(⌊n/3⌋+1). Which seems to be the correct answer. What I am having trouble with is assigning this to a more general Theta like:[Theta Choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPWgc.png)

This is the first time dealing with floors in analysis so I don't know what impact they have on this. I would really appreciate some guidance in figuring out the Theta for this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just imagine what the floors cause. If you increase `n`, the execution time is basically quantized to a discrete set. But that does not change the overall behavior of the function (just its precision if you will). So just ignore them and you get a complexity of `n log n`.

Comment: So would you say that the floors at least most of the time could be ignored when performing complexity analysis?

Comment: At least I cannot think of an example where it would matter. But that does not mean that it does not exist.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your help Nico!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In time complexity you don't really care about constants so you have that your algorithm is `Θ((⌊log3 (n)⌋+1) ×(⌊n/3⌋+1))` which is simple `Θ(nlog3(n)).`
Also you don't care about the base of the logarithm because log3(n)=c*log(n) so again you don't count constants so the right answer is:

`Θ(nlog(n)).`